# Как узнать groupId и artifactId создаваемого в Idea jar'а?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Я собрал `jar` в `Intellij Idea`(Build-Build Artifacts) одного своего проекта, чтобы подключить его ко второму, но второй собирается с помощью `Maven`, то есть мне надо в `pom.xml` прописать зависимости, мне требуется знать groupId, artifactId и версию своего же `jar`, как это сделать?

Comment: Полагаю такие, какие заданы в вашей системе сборки первого проекта. И кстати что бы подключить jar к проекту надо не только знать его groupId, artifactId, но и что бы он лежал в мавен репозитории и что бы система сборки второго проекта знала об этом репозитории.

Comment: @xkor Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Я бы поступил так: конвертнул ваш проэкт (тот из которого вы собрали "свой jar") в мейвен прожект соответственно можно указать конкретные значения для artifact id + group id. Большинство IDE умеет подтягивать мейвен зависимости из прожектов открытых в IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя первый проект собирается Maven'ом, то:

1. Смотришь groupId, artifactId и version в pom.xml проекта, который хочешь иметь в зависимостях, выполняешь mvn install, что бы Maven установил артефакт в локальный репозиторий.
2. Прописываешь в зависимости созданный артефакт.

Если нет, то во втором проекте прописываешь плагин. [Вот здесь сказано, как](http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/). Но всё таки лучше первый проект сделать тоже maven-проектом.